# Match word before colon except if line begins with hyphen

Tags: regex

I am using this RegEx to match a word before a colon.

```
([^\s]+)\:
```

However, how would I change this so it will only match the word if the line **does not** begin with a hyphen/dash?

**EDIT**

Should match:

```
     [object doSomething:foo];
```

Shouldn't match:

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSString *)string;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[^:-].*?:\s*
```

Should do the trick. (Assuming that the `DOT_ALL` modifier is not used.)

```
[^:-] // One char, not a hyphen or colon
.*? // Perhaps more, non-greedy
:\s* // Colon and optionally spaces
```

Ergo: At least one character before the first colon. First character cannot be a hyphen or colon.

Alternatively `^[^:-][^:]*:\s*` if you find that easier to read.

---

**EDIT**:
According to comment this was what solved OPs problem:

```
^([^:-][^:]*):
```

Comment: Oops, updated - I, wrongfully, stated that `.+?` was "Perhaps more, non-greedy". It should have been `.*?` to fulfil the "perhaps" part :)

Comment: Works in part however it highlights everything before the colon not just the word.

Comment: @Joshua Yes, the grouping wasn't there to begin with :) Try `^([^:-][^:]*):\s*`.

Comment: @Joshua Alternatively, `^([^\s:-][^\s]*)\:` to reflect your updated question.

Comment: @Joshua Could you please post a permalink to the tests you are doing.

Comment: Ah, that works better but it won't match even if the line starts with a letter or a space rather than just a hyphen.

Comment: I just use this text `AColon:SomeOtherText` to check if it works.

Comment: @Joshua Should it? You should probably update your question with a list of what to match and what to exclude.

Comment: I've updated the question to list exactly what it should and shouldn't match.

Comment: Confused: http://regexpal.com/?flags=m&regex=^%28[^%3A-][^%3A]*%29%3A&input=-%20%28void%29doSomething%3A%28NSString%20*%29string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20[object%20doSomething%3Afoo]%3B perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression in multiline mode:

```
^[^\r\n:-][^\r\n:]*:\s*
```

Comment: Works in part however it highlights everything before the colon not just the word.

Comment: @Joshua: Yes, as this pattern matches everything except from a `-` from the begin of the line up to the colon inclusive as well as any following whitespace (except new lines), RegexPal highlights the whole matched string.

Comment: I see, is there anyway to make it just highlight the word when using the Regex? I am using this with `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: @Joshua: You could use a look-ahead assertion `(?=…)` to only assert that a colon is following: `^[^\r\n:-][^\r\n:]*(?=:\s*)`. Then the colon is not matched.

Comment: That's good but it still matches everything before the colon not just the word before the colon. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: @Joshua: Define word. What word do you mean? By the way: If you try to parse the language Objective-C, better use a proper parser.

Comment: By word I mean whatever is before the colon until a space. What proper parsers are there?

Comment: Objective-C that is why I was using `NSRegularExpression` to process a string using these Regular Expressions.

Comment: @Joshua: I’m not familiar with Objective-C. But there probably is a parser or tokenizer for Objective-C written in Objective-C. You could ask another question to get an answer to that. :)

Comment: Yeh, I guess so. I thought it may have been possible to do it with RegEx. If there's a look-ahead is there a look-behind to check if the line begins with a hyphen to stop it highlighting it all?

Comment: @Joshua: As I said, I’m not that familiar with Objective-C and I don’t know if there are cases where this can fail (like in comments, strings, etc.). So you’re better off with a proper parser that can handle these cases.